# How to run a block of code only for the first element of a array in Ruby-on-rails?

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux

I want to run a block of code only for the first element of a array.
I have the following code as of now

```
$data = YAML.load_file(yml_file_to_load)
    @Alarms = $data['Alarms']
    @Alarms.each do |alarm|
    
          describe "Test code is going start from here", :test do
```

This particular code run the block for every element in the array @Alarms. I want the code to run only for first element that is the code has to run only once.

Note that I also want to preserve the value of `alarm` variable inside the block.  Here the variable should contain first element of array.

Comment: This code is pretty perplexing - if you're using RSpec you should be using `let/let!` if this is mini-test with spec syntax you should be setting this up with fixtures and the `setup` method. What are  you doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you only want to test the first element of the array then just assign the element to a variable, for example like this:

```
before do
  data = YAML.load_file(yml_file_to_load)
  @alarm = data['Alarms'][0]
end

describe "Test code is going start from here", :test do
  # use @alarm in the test
```

Comment: Is there any way I can get the value in `alarm` rather than `@alarm` ?

Comment: @mac I am not sure if I understand our question? What is wrong with using `@alarm`? If you want to use `alarm` instead just replace `before do` with `def alarm` and let the `alarm` method return that one element

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object#tap` to yield any object to a block:

```
$data = YAML.load_file(yml_file_to_load) # Why are you using a global?
@alarms = $data['alarms'] # variables should be snakecase
@alarms.first.tap do |alarm|
  # ...
end
```

`tap` returns the original object. So its useful when you're only interested in the side effects.  If you want to use the return value of the block use `then`:

```
result = @alarms.first.then do |alarm|
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately with ` @alarms.first.tap do |alarm|` statement the code between `do |alarm|` and  `end` is not working.

Comment: You do understand that I can't help you with some mystery code that you just wrote?